# write form into cover letter

Tags: grammaticality

> Today morning I have faced a viva-voce exam, and I did good in exam.

How will I write this as formal cover-letter with 100 % Grammatically accuracy? What tense is good for mentioning this? past tense or present perfect tense?

Comment: "did good" is not good English. It would be better as *did well* in *the* exam.

Comment: What do you mean by "Today morning"? This is unnatural and not used in English speaking parts of the world.

Comment: @Trist, probably OP means "this morning", but I'm wondering if, instead, we can say "yesterday morning".

Comment: Carlo, "this morning" would be correct if they are talking about the morning of the same day. For example, if the exam was taken in the morning of the 4th of May 2013 and the OP mentioned it in the afternoon of the 4th of May 2013. Saying "yesterday morning" would be correct if they are talking about the morning of the day before the current one. For example, if the exam was taken in the morning of the 3rd of May 2013 and the OP mentioned it on the the 4th of May 2013.

Comment: This looks like proof-reading to me.

Comment: Hi Laser-boy, welcome to ELL! I see your question has been answered, which is good, but questions like this are considered "proofreading" are are not generally allowed on this site. In the future, please point out which parts of the sentence you think might be wrong, and why. This will help us see what you're thinking, and give better answers. It will also make the question allowable on the site :)  Thanks, and I hope to see more from you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break this down:

> Today morning

This should be "**This morning**." (Note that you should normally put a comma after introductory phrases like this, but if the sentence is short—like this one is—it will flow better without a comma.)

> I have faced

Do you notice the verb difference between here and second half of the sentence? Here we have the present perfect, and there we have the simple past. If you are talking about something that is completely done (as the exam probably is, because you said that you know that you did well), then the simple past is probably better. So, I would make this "**I faced**."

> viva-voce

I'm not sure if this term has really entered the English lexicon. As such, it should probably be italicized as a foreign phrase (it's Latin). I think you should also drop the hyphen: "***viva voce***."

> good

"Good" should be an adverb here, because you are explaining *how* you "did" on the exam. This word is "**well**."

> in exam

This sounds rather awkward. I would probably change it to "on the exam." However, because you were just talking about the exam (and because the sentence is so short), it makes more sense to just **drop these words**.

---

All that gives us:

> This morning I faced a *viva voce* exam, and I did well.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thnx got you :-)